# Pass parameters to my executable at debugging time visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution wich its first Project need some parameters the  user and password,

How can  I do to supply those parameters directly from de IDE in visual studio. This for debuging purposes to avoid type it each time I run a test.

Comment: Excelent. You are ok, I'm spending 4 hours and can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your project in the Solution Explorer, right click and select Properties.
In the Debug Tab you will find a textbox named `Command Line Arguments`